# Promise with setTimeout - непонятна работа в цикле

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise, async-await

Пытаюсь добиться последовательного выполнения внутри цикла

```
async function f(){
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(()=>{console.log("f")}, 2000));
        console.log(index)
    }
}
f();
// Результат выводит один раз f
```

Как добиться вывода?

```
f
0
f
1
f
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо не забывать, что промис должен быть либо разрешён (resolve) либо отклонён (reject). У вас нет как минимум одной этой важной детали.

```js
async function f(){
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve("f"), 1000)
        });
        
        let result = await promise;
        console.log(result)
        console.log(index)
    }
}
f();
```

---

```js
async function f(){
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('f');
              resolve();
            }, 1000)
        });
        
        console.log(index)
    }
}
f();
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно

Comment: Только не понятно. почему без создания переменной let promise, await не работал?

Comment: Читайте комментарий вначале... там дело не совсем в переменной... смотрите код внимательней

Comment: А, получается setTimeout возвращает resolve, который на самом деле вернётся через секунду, и мы его ждём в result, так?

Comment: Добавил второй пример, чтоб было прям наглядно

Comment: setTimeout  ничего не возвращает.... Это PROMISE должен быть дать ответную реакцию.... промис можно либо зарезолвить либо зареджектить. это **обязательное условие** работы с промисами  ...   (https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

> почему без создания переменной let promise, await не работал?

Он просто не заканчивался. В нем не вызывался ни `resolve`, ни `reject`

Вот - все работает и без переменной.

```js
async function f(){
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(_ => {
          console.log("f")
          resolve()
        }, 2000));
        console.log(index)
    }
}
f();
```